# Underbrace and equations: spacing between terms

Tags: equations, text, split, underbrace

In the code below, I am able to label the different terms of the equation. However, the equal, addition and subtraction signs aren't in the middle of each of the terms. Ideally, I would be able to force them to be exactly in the middle of the terms and to have all terms space out equally so it looks neater. Is there any way of doing this?

Thank you

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underbrace{\rho T\dfrac{D s}{D t}}_{\substack{\text{Entropy}\\\text{advection}}} = \underbrace{\dot{q}}_{\substack{\text{Heat}\\\text{addition}}} - \underbrace{\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{q}}_{\substack{\text{Heat}\\\text{transfer}}} + 
\underbrace{\tau:(\nabla \boldsymbol{u})}_{\substack{\text{Viscous}\\\text{effects}}} - \underbrace{\rho\sum^{N}_{i=1}\left(\dfrac{\mu_i}{W_i}\right)\dfrac{DY_i}{Dt}}_{\substack{\text{Chemical}\\\text{reactions}}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

EDIT:

After egreg's suggestion, I have copied over the command:

[image]

and loaded amsmath, but am getting these errors:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the long words that exceed the length of the brace.

You can solve the problem by making them zero width and by doubling the default spaces around relation and operation symbols, except around `\dot{q}`.

I also add a local command `\?` to make all braces at the same level.

In order to remedy to brace frenzy, I define an `\ubracetext` command that simplifies input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\ubracetext}{mm}
 {
  {% make the thing an ordinary atom
   \underbrace { #1 } \sb { \jrjrjr_ubrace_text:n { #2 } }
  }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \jrjrjr_ubrace_text:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \text{\vphantom{Ay}##1} }
  \substack { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \\ } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\def\?{\vphantom{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^N}}
%
\ubracetext{\?\rho T\dfrac{D s}{D t}}{Entropy \\ \makebox[0pt]{advection}}
\;=
\ubracetext{\?\dot{q}}{Heat \\ \makebox[0pt]{addition}}
-\;
\ubracetext{\?\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{q}}{Heat \\ \makebox[0pt]{transfer}}
\;+\; 
\ubracetext{\?\tau:(\nabla \boldsymbol{u})}{Viscous \\ effects}
\;-\;
\ubracetext{\?\rho\sum^{N}_{i=1}\left(\dfrac{\mu_i}{W_i}\right)\dfrac{DY_i}{Dt}}%
  {Chemical \\ reactions}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg. This looks exactly how I wanted it to -- but, unfortunately, I'm having a hard time emulating this in my overleaf document. I have copied over the new command and I am loading the amsmath package. However, I'm getting errors (I've edited the question to show the errors I'm getting).

Comment: @jrjrjr The error seems related to microtype. please, make a minimal example of code showing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The code and solution provided works on a separate blank article (such as yours) as well as on a blank thesis template -- but gives an error in my thesis file even though I've loaded the same packages in all three cases... Unsure how to unblock this situation. Open to suggestions!

Comment: @jrjrjr Sorry, but I can't help without more details and a minimal example of failing code.

Comment: Fixed an issue with the compiler and it solved my microtype error -- thank you!